# Is it restful to have verbs on the HTTP path instead of the HTTP method?

Tags: design-patterns, rest, api-design

I've encountered API that tell as being "restful" but then I see resources with verbs instead of reserving those said verbs to the `METHOD`.
Here's some (paths shortened so only the relevant method and path parts are shown):

1. `POST /things/84/lock`
2. `POST /things/84/unlock`
3. `POST /things/84/edit`
4. `POST /things/prepend` (Adding to the beginning of the ordered collection)

Why doesn't it make sense to do instead:

1. `LOCK /things/84`
2. `UNLOCK /things/84`
3. `PATCH /things/84` or `EDIT /things/84` (I prefer the first one)
4. `PREFIX /things` or `PREPEND /things`

I've only been told again and again that this is not restful because it must only use GET, POST, PUT, DELETE and PATCH to remain restful.

What logical explanation exists for having verbs in the path section of the URL for restful API?

**Notes:**

1. I can't show you real life examples so I won't be pointing fingers
   at anybody.
2. As for proxy limitations excuse I've been experiencing. It was valid while no workaround existed. Nowadays, most modern frameworks have mechanisms to allow method override using query variables or headers (with de-facto standards, even).

Comment: Partial answer as to why someone might have put the "verbs" in the url: it's quite possible that the API was written before "modern" frameworks that could handle something other than GET and POST.  And not everyone wants to (or has time to) rewrite / upgrade their API every time technology and frameworks take a step forward.  Legacy code is a thing, a huge thing.

Comment: Thank you @becuzz Now what's missing for me is understanding why should be kept that way for new API on a new system.

Comment: No, that is definitely not RESTful. In REST, an URL should indicate a resource but not an action. There might be good reasons for the design, but it is wrong to call it RESTful.

Comment: If you want to do that, just use RPC. It's basically the same thing, despite what REST zealots will say.

Comment: Change your point of view. The aim of REST over HTTP is to allow any application with a **http client** to consume your API. HTTP clients don't care what is in the URI path. They care about *speaking http*. LOCK, UNLOCK, PREFIX are not in its vocabulary. Basically these won't make sense for anyone but for your own system. If you don't want your API to be consumed world-wide by any http client, then go with these verbs. But, how whatsisaname say. If you don't need the ergonomy of the WWW, then go with RPC, where you can tunnel any verb you want and still be www-firendly

Comment: In other words **HTTP is a protocol for machines not for humans**. So stop thinking in REST as if It was going to be read by humans. HTTP clients are far to be it.

Comment: @Laiv The one who processes it are not humans but the ones who need to understand and make logic out of it are humans. The same way as code is for machines, not humans.... but we still strive into making good code and getting techniques into making code legible.

Comment: "Speaking http" has nothing to do with readability. In this case you reasoning is wrong. You are moving human and concrete business conocerns to something meant to be agnostic to both. If you find HTTP not to be enough to met your needs, instead of overhauling a well-known and reliable protocol, consider picking one more adecuate to your needs. Mutating a good one might lead you to unexpected situations with unexpected side effects. Adecuacy is always your best choice.

Comment: Additionally, many frameworks and HTTP clients are implemented according the HTTP RFCs. You can decide ignore these resources and code your own frameworks or clients. However, the cost of such efforts are hard to sell to anyone who already know that what you want to do is totally unecessary.

Comment: Finally, I'm sure that you have not taking into account the implications of unknow verbs in one of the most important (and not trivial) properties of REST. **Caching**. Inventing http verbs is not exempt of side effects since the Network topology it's unkown for you all the time. It can change anytime and these changes will not take into account our specific needs for readability. :-)

Comment: Worth [reading](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it restful to have verbs on the HTTP path instead of the HTTP method?

Yes.  REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your identifiers.

> I've only been told again and again that this is not restful because it must only use GET, POST, PUT, DELETE and PATCH to remain restful.

One of the REST architecture constraints is the [uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5); describing it in his thesis, Fielding wrote

> By applying the software engineering principle of generality to the component interface, the overall system architecture is simplified and the visibility of interactions is improved. Implementations are decoupled from the services they provide, which encourages independent evolvability....

There's nothing particularly magic about [GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH]. A very long time ago, that list would probably be [GET, HEAD, POST], because those were the only methods that had been standardized in [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-5.1.1).  The others were documented with [this warning](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#appendix-D.1):

> This appendix documents protocol elements used by some existing HTTP implementations, but not consistently and correctly across most HTTP/1.0 applications. Implementors should be aware of these features, but cannot rely upon their presence in, or interoperability with, other HTTP/1.0 applications.

The interoperability is key, in that it means that clients and servers and intermediary components that share an understanding of the message semantics can all cooperate together to produce a result -- *without* needing to understand the payload of the message.

Today, we have a [method registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml), with many different methods that you might want to use, including (as it happens) LOCK and UNLOCK.  So, assuming your semantics agrees with those documented in the registry, you could use them.

In circumstances where you control both the client and the server, limiting yourself to the registered methods is less critical than it would be otherwise.

If you are targeting clients that understand code on demand, then you can give a generic client a link to download your client code to interact with your services.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of problems with using custom HTTP methods that mean it's rarely a good idea.  Some of these are:

- Some proxy servers and firewalls will not forward requests using them
- Implementing them often requires custom server configuration that may not be possible on shared hosts (thus preventing the use of such services)
- The semantics of the method may be unclear (is a call to your custom method idempotent?  We know that a call to a PUT method should be, and that a POST method likely isn't, which is a clear benefit of using those two method types)
- A key feature of RESTful services is the ability to discover operations that can be performed on a resource automatically (i.e. [HATEOAS](https://restfulapi.net/hateoas/)).  But the standard techniques (e.g. the [use of link elements in xml documents](http://restcookbook.com/Resources/link-types/) or [JSON-LD](https://json-ld.org/)) for doing this only provide the means of specifying the URI to use for such an operation, not what request method should be used.  This therefore impacts discoverability of your API.

Generally speaking, using a `/noun-type/specific-noun-identifier/verb` structure is easier and more understandable than custom HTTP methods, so why go to the effort when it has potential negative consequences?

Comment: 1* Is moot for nowadays, as per what I mentioned in the question.  
2* On the receiver end, you mean? If so, how so? It's just a string!  
3* The current standard rfc states that all methods not specified should be assumed to be non-idempotent and not safe. Regardless, an  `OPTIONS` method call can clarify that. IMO, This is the only one that can be used to opose.
4* Use the `OPTIONS` method. You know the resource exists, now just ask what it allows you to do to it.

Do note I never mean to have methods to do operations that are already specified. This is for things not specified in RFC.

Comment: "1* Is moot for nowadays" -- is it?  The last time I worked in an environment that had a firewall that prevented such things was only a couple of years ago, so I'm pretty sure there must still be some locations where it happens.  "how so? It's just a string" -- yes, but server configuration may prevent it being passed to your processing scripts (e.g. PHP has an option `http.request.methods.allowed` that can be used to limit the allowed methods). "Use the OPTIONS method" -- which requires an extra round trip to the server.  Yes, of all these problems only the first is a showstopper, but what...

Comment: ...do you gain by working around them?

Comment: 1*: It is. On the server, you can control. On clients with IT stuck in the past, there's workarounds.  
2*: Just change the server configuration.  
3*:The `OPTIONS` request only needs to be used once when making the API calls.  
As for gains: I gain semantics. You do X on Y. For example, I don't POST onto a lock resource. I lock a resource. I don't post an item into a prepend resource of a collection. I prepend a document on a resource collection. Do these examples help?

Comment: 1*: I work every day with customers that have proxy rules regarding HTTP methods (PUT and DELETE overall). They also block X-like headers. 2* changing http severs is not always in your hands. And not always you are totally aware of the vulnerabilities you might be exposing a system due to a uncommon configurations. 3* if you want your own semantics, use other protocols that also works over tcp/ip. Or like has been commented, do use other semantics as RPC. HTTP has no more methods for a reason. The protocol should be untied from the "business" that operates over.

Comment: 1*: Do they block query variables too? Anyhow, the HTTP method is a string with only ASCII characters. How maliciously misused can a string be? 2* Again, it's a string that mentions what is wanted to be done. If you don't want to permit it, just configure to return 405 or 501 status code. Block sending it makes no sense but there's workarounds. rfc7231 does not limit the methods available but it specifies a standard set. 3* There's actually, currently, [39 official HTTP methods.](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use a custom "verb," there is a mechanism in place for this already: [verb tunneling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/http-verb-tunneling) via the the [x-http-method-override header](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541471.aspx). This gives you the benefits and avoids most of the pitfalls that Jules listed.

> It is possible to instruct network intermediaries (proxies, firewalls, and so on) inspecting traffic at the application protocol layer (for example, HTTP) to block requests that contain certain HTTP verbs. In practice, GET and POST verbs are rarely blocked (traditional web pages rely heavily on these HTTP methods), while, for a variety of reasons (such as security vulnerabilities in prior protocols), other HTTP methods (PUT, DELETE, and so on) are at times blocked by intermediaries. Additionally, some existing HTTP libraries do not allow creation of requests using verbs other than GET or POST. Therefore, an alternative way of specifying request types which use verbs other than GET and POST is needed to ensure that this document works well in a wide range of environments.
>
> To address this need, the X-HTTP-Method header can be added to a POST request that signals that the server MUST process the request not as a POST, but as if the HTTP verb specified as the value of the header was used as the method on the HTTP request's request line, as specified in [RFC2616] section 5.1. This technique is often referred to as "verb tunneling".

Comment: Of course, doing so will raise the blood pressure of the Church of REST's members.

Comment: REST are achitrctural properties and constraints. It has nothing do with the protocol in use. Anyways, the trick commented here is addressed to bypass constraints, not to pass forward custom verbs. If you have to do so, go RPC. Is still the same, but with your own semantics.

Comment: @JohnWu Although you are right, you are not answering the question.